# When you clone a a Backbone.Collection are the model references intact?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm .clone() -ing a collection so that I can use a splice loop on it and not interfere with the original. Are the models in cloned array originals or copies?

What I need is a copy of the array with the original models in it.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get the same models as the source collection wrapped in a new collection of the same type.

Here is the implementation of collection.clone:

```
   clone: function() {
      return new this.constructor(this.models);
    },
```

Or if you prefer a deep clone, override Backbone.Collection.clone

```
clone: function(deep) {
  if(deep) {
    return new this.constructor(_.map(this.models, function(m) { return m.clone(); }));
  }else{
    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.clone();
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/9bk4d/

Comment: No worries.  If you ever get hung up just read the annotated source.  http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Comment: why would I use this? I mean, usually, if I clone things, I want them not to hold *any* reference to the old collection, *especially* not the models!

Comment: @raffomania There are times where clone comes in handy.  Client side filtering, paging and sorting to name a few.  If you prefer a deep clone just override backbones clone.